# use aplpy figure in an AxesSubplot instance

Tags: python, matplotlib, aplpy

I have defined a grid of figures in matplotlib using `subplots` as in this example:

```
f, axarr = plt.subplots(2)
axarr[0].plot(x, y)
```

Is it possible to plot a figure generated by `aplpy.FITSFigure` in one of the axes instances returned by `subplots`?